# Why can't returns infer the type of the return, and I have to explicitly return instead of using closures?

Tags: rust

I was doing basic exercises:

```rust
pub fn bigger(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let biggest = if a > b { a } else { return b };
}
```

The compiler reports an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:1:34
  |
1 | pub fn bigger(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
  |        ------                    ^^^ expected `i32`, found `()`
  |        |
  |        implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
```

I don't understand why the compiler finds an `()`. From what I understand, since the closure returns `a` or `b` in `biggest`, should I change the code (for example, add biggest the line after, or biggest; or basically return a or b).

Where is the problem? If I return `biggest` by adding a line it compiles as expected. Why is the compiler unable to infer the return type?

Does the `let` return something? I know I've missed something but seem to understand what.

The goal here is to understand what Rust is doing, since I feel I can't get a grasp on some concepts and not have the best code possible.

Comment: There are **no** closures in this code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's understand your code to more clearly see what happens.

```
pub fn bigger(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let biggest = if a > b { a } else { return b };
}
```

You're creating a locally-scoped binding with the name `biggest`. If `a > b` it will have value of `a`, else the function will `return b`.

So for `a > b` there is no implicit or explicit return value for this function.

In this function, there is no need for an explicitly named `biggest` binding. You can use Rust's property of implicit returns:

```
pub fn bigger(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    if a > b {
        a
    } else {
        b
    }
}
```

I should mention that this function is equivalent to [`std::cmp::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.max.html) from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Complementary to [Inline's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64432824/155423):

> Why is the compiler unable to infer the return type?

It's not. It's telling you that your types don't match: you declare that `bigger` returns an `i32` but it does not.

> Does the `let` return something?

No, `let` is a statement.

> I know I've missed something but seem to understand what.

`let` does its thing. Since there's nothing afterwards, execution "falls off" the end of the function, which doesn't return anything, therefore implicitly returning `()` (exactly what the compiler tells you).

Since that doesn't match the declared return type of `i32`, you get a compilation error.